# Disable auto-insert of double quotes in html in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, autocomplete, double-quotes

Is it possible to do this? I can't find anything in the Options that disables this.

For example, if I type

```
<table cellpadding=
```

it automatically inserts "" and positions the cursor between the two quotes. This is not what I prefer to do. I prefer to type without quotes, and then select the text and format it -- it is much quicker. In previous versions of Visual Studio, it did the auto-insert by default, but I was able to disable it. I can't find a way to do it in Visual Studio 2013. Disabling "brace completion" does not work. It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML

- General ->  Automatic brace completion
- Advanced -> Insert attribute
  value quotes

or/and in HTML (Web Forms)

- Formatting -> Insert attribute value quotes when typing

Comment: I have turned off all three of these options (in 2017) and the undesireable behaviour still occurs... any suggestions?

Comment: @Matt do you have  resharper?  That might also be doing it.